# Concatenating a few strings

Tags: string, assembly, string-concatenation, lc3

Do you have any idea about this problem?

Question:

> Write and execute an LC-3 assembly program which concatenates two strings. The first string begins at memory address x4000, and the second string begins at memory address x5000. Strings always terminate with a 0.

```
Example​:Before​ your program executes:
M[x4000] = 5 M[x5000] = 6
M[x4001] = 2 M[x5001] = 1
M[x4002] = 8 M[x5002] = 8
M[x4003] = 4 M[x5003] = 0
M[x4004] = 0

After​ your program executes:
M[x4000] = 5 M[x5000] = 6
M[x4001] = 2 M[x5001] = 1
M[x4002] = 8 M[x5002] = 8
M[x4003] = 4 M[x5003] = 0
M[x4004] = 6 M[x4005] = 1
M[x4006] = 8 M[x4007] = 0
```

Comment: This is the C function `strcat`, in case you want to look for example implementations in C.

Comment: You don't know where to start.  That's a difficult situation for our Q&A format, because
 naturally we're not going to just give you solution to the homework, and, we don't know what you're truly stuck with, whether a specific question about LC-3, registers, memory, arrays, pointers, loops.  You'll probably find better luck at a mentoring site, like codementor.io.

Comment: @ErikEidt Hey, Thanks for your answer. I just dont know how can I concatenat to a few strings. I mean I checked internet but I coultn get any solution for lc-3

Comment: If you can do it in C that will help.

Comment: If you want a different kind of help than Q&A, such as mentoring, to learn what you need to know to complete this assignment, see me at [codementor.io](https://www.codementor.io/@erikeidt).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea: write a loop to locate the address of the first zero word starting from 0x4000. Once you've found that, write another loop that will copy words from 0x5000 and further to that address, terminating once the zero byte is copied.